# Using Netscaler datastream and MySQL

Tags: mysql, load-balancing, mysqlslap

I configured MySQL service on a netscaler 10.5. When I perform some MySQL benchmarks using `mysqlslap`, the first time it runs correctly, the 2nd time I have an error message:

When I run it the first time:

```
mysqlslap -hlb_mysql --concurrency=10 --iterations=1 --number-int-cols=2 
          --number-char-cols=3 --auto-generate-sql --auto-generate-sql-load-type=read 
          --engine=InnoDB
Benchmark
        Running for engine InnoDB
        Average number of seconds to run all queries: 0.044 seconds
        Minimum number of seconds to run all queries: 0.044 seconds
        Maximum number of seconds to run all queries: 0.044 seconds
        Number of clients running queries: 10
        Average number of queries per client: 0
```

When I run it the 2nd time:

```
mysqlslap: Cannot run query CREATE TABLE `t1` (intcol1 INT(32) ,intcol2 INT(32) ,
           charcol1 VARCHAR(128),charcol2 VARCHAR(128),charcol3 VARCHAR(128)) 
           ERROR : No database selected
```

When I wait a few minutes, it runs correctly again. After executing, I see about 16 persistent connection on the database originating from the NetScaler.

Any ideas how I could solve this problem?

Comment: So... you are trying to run mysqlslap against (potentially) multiple MySQL servers at the same time through the Netscaler?

Comment: Yes, the goal is to be able to use multiple MySQL slave servers through the Netscaler and use it's read/write splitting capabilities to be able to offload the MySQL Master server.

Comment: Currently all queries are routed to the same (master) MySQL server.